# Как программно определить на какой странице находится определенный элемент в документе word?

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml

Задача программно сгенирировать документ Word, а именно договор.
Для договора есть определенные правила того что если заголовок начинается с новой страницы надо что бы часть текста с предыдущей страницы попадала на новую, что бы страница не могла начаться с заголовка, например:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что бы соблюсти это требование, необходимо определить на какой странице и в какой ее части находиться элемент, в данном случае заголовок, как это можно сделать с использованием openXml?

Answer (score 0):

Вот так можно узнать на какой странице находится элемент программно:

```csharp
int currentPageNumber = wordApp.Selection.Information[WdInformation.wdActiveEndPageNumber];
```

Будет получен номер страницы на которой находится курсор.

Также существует еще один вариант [ссылка на cyberforum](https://www.cyberforum.ru/windows-forms/thread2448141.html#post14551770)